Nagios 4.4.12 notification error: (No output on stdout) stderr on ESXi hardware check
Excuse me but I'm new to Nagios.
We are facing an issue with Nagios v4.4.12 where a WARNING notification keeps popping up against our ESXi hosts.
Notifications page
Below is the ESXi Hardware Check status information:
Current Status:   WARNING   (for 3d 22h 36m 47s)
Status Information: (No output on stdout) stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_esxi_hardware.py", line 773, in <module>
c=wbemclient.EnumerateInstances('CIM_Chassis')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pywbem/_cim_operations.py", line 3058, in EnumerateInstances
result = self._imethodcall(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pywbem/_cim_operations.py", line 1955, in _imethodcall
reply_data, self._last_server_response_time = wbem_request(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pywbem/_cim_http.py", line 568, in wbem_request
raise AuthError(msg, conn_id=conn.conn_id)
pywbem._exceptions.AuthError: WBEM server returned HTTP status 401 (Unauthorized). This is most likely an issue with userid/password, but for servers that implement resource access control it might also be an issue with the permissions of the userid.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_esxi_hardware.py", line 774, in <module>
except pywbem.cim_operations.CIMError as args:
AttributeError: module 'pywbem' has no attribute 'cim_operations'. Did you mean: '_cim_operations'?

Those are the Notification Commands output:
notify-host-by-chat:
/usr/bin/printf "ALERT" | /usr/local/nagios/etc/notify-teams.py "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$" "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host: $HOSTNAME$ State: $HOSTSTATE$ Address: $HOSTADDRESS$ Info: $HOSTOUTPUT$ Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$" <our Teams webhook>

notify-host-by-email:
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$

Based on below line of the error I've tried finding the user in question but without success:
pywbem._exceptions.AuthError: WBEM server returned HTTP status 401 (Unauthorized). This is most likely an issue with userid/password, but for servers that implement resource access control it might also be an issue with the permissions of the userid.

Let me know if I can provide anything from our configuration that might help and I'll be happy to assist!

tried finding the user in question but without success - if the user doesn't exist it would explain the login problem. Creating the user with the correct password should solve it.
